# Collision between two GPS points

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, gps

I would like to do sphere to sphere intersection or ellipsoid to ellipsoid if I have two GPS coordinate points. What is the formula for that ?

Suppose I have two GPS points with two different lon,lat,alt. I would like to do sphere to sphere intersection or ellipsoid to ellipsoid. Is there a formula for that ?

```
    WGS84toXYZ(xAv, yAv, zAv, (m_sPosAV.GetLongitude()*math::pi) / 180, (m_sPosAV.GetLatitude()*math::pi) / 180, (m_sPosAV.GetAltitude()*math::pi) / 180); // lon direction Nort
    WGS84toXYZ(xPoi, yPoi, zPoi, (poi.Position().GetLongitude()*math::pi) / 180, (poi.Position().GetLatitude()*math::pi) / 180, (poi.Position().GetAltitude()*math::pi) / 180); // lon direction Nort

    Sphere avSphere;
    Sphere poiSphere;

    avSphere.position.x = xAv;
    avSphere.position.y = yAv;
    avSphere.position.z = 0;
    avSphere.radius = 1550000;
    poiSphere.position.x = xPoi;
    poiSphere.position.y = yPoi;
    poiSphere.position.z = 0;
    poiSphere.radius = 100000;

    if (doesItCollide(avSphere, poiSphere))
    {
        qDebug() << "collision sphere";
    }
```

Comment: If you have only latitude and longitude, you're dealing with circles and not spheres.
Detect the collision between two spheres is easy : the circles are colliding if the distance between the center is lower than the sum of the rayon of each circle.

Comment: I have the latitude, longitude, and altitude, that's why I want to do sphere to sphere intersection not circles

Comment: I have converted the spherical coordinates to Cartesian coordinates, but the collision is always occuring

Answer (score 0):

Sphere is easy:
If distance between your 2 points is smaller than the sum of your radii for the spheres, you got yourself an intersection.